# how to have backwards reference on PHP's regex?

Tags: php, regex

Can i use backward reference on any PHP regexp method?

for example, on most languages i can have:

```
<?php
$r = /KEY=(['"])[^\1]*\1/
// or more simply
$r = /KEY=(['"])VAL\1/
```

Which will match `KEY="VAL"` and `KEY='VAL'` but not get confused with `KEY="mismatch 'quotes' in val"` as the simpler `$r=/KEY=['"].*?['"]/` would.

Do any PHP method accepts this? NOTE, just to make it clear, this is not about using matching references (or matching groups) in the replacement portion.

Comment: What is the question? PHP supports backreferences in the pattern to reference previously captured text.

Comment: Just to be clear, yes PHP does support back references. No it doesn't support what you have written `[^\1]`. This will basically match anything not `1`. To simulate this effect you could use `(?:(?!\1).)*`

Comment: thanks @HamZa this is what was driving me insane. i will write something explaning your solution and submit to the php docs that miken32 put on his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is [almost fully](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php) PCRE-compatible. As such, [it does support backreferences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php).

```
$r = "/KEY=(['\"])VAL\1/";
```